# Unable to detect an error in a basic bar chart using python x pandas on Jupiter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am working on a CSV called `application_train` that has data about credit applicants. One of the column of the CSV is `DAYS_BIRTH`, which represents the age of applicants in - days. 
I've divided the data by - `365.25` to get it in years, and rounded that.

Here are my imports

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Now, I want to plot a bar chart but it doesn't work and there is no error notice on my Jupyter notebook so I don't really know what's wrong.

Here's what I've done to convert it in years:

```
application_train['AGE'] = round(application_train['DAYS_BIRTH']/-365.25) 
application_train['AGE']
```

Here's the output :

```
0         26.0
1         46.0
2         52.0
3         52.0
4         55.0
          ... 
307506    26.0
307507    57.0
307508    41.0
307509    33.0
307510    46.0
Name: AGE, Length: 307511, dtype: float64
```

Then I added this to get a bar chart :

`application_train['AGE'].plot(kind="bar", title=" Distribution by age")`

But at this step, nothing happens when I execute. 
The cell is "running" (instead of having an intput number, I have a *, it looks like In[*])

No chart and no error notice. 
What is the best way to fix this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: how about `matplotlib.pyplot.show()` to force python to display it ?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the code. I think you forgot to `import matplotlib` for inline display in Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: Hi, here are my imports 
`
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
`

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = [23, 23, 24, 25, 56, 67, 78]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Age'])

bar_data = df.Age

bar_data.plot(kind="bar", title=" Distribution by age")
```

[image]